# Increase the size of a Pseudo-element on css animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a **css animation** which animates a line to move from left to right as well as right to left or in a ***CSSey*** way an `::after` element which is translated on the **x-axis** from **0 to 300% and back to 0%**

I want to start the animation with default size and scale the size of the element(::after) horizontally when its around the middle portion then go back to the default size at end and vice versa.

I tried adding `50% { transform: scale(1.5)}` but this isn't what i want.

```js
const faqContainer = document.querySelector('.faq-box')
const faqBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.faq')

const displayIcons = () => {
  faqBoxes.forEach(box => {
    const toggler = document.createElement('i')
    toggler.className = `toggler fas fa-chevron-down`
    box.appendChild(toggler)
  })
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', displayIcons)

const showFaqContent = event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('toggler') || event.target.classList.contains('faq-title')) {
    const parentElem = event.target.parentElement
    const eventElmClassList = event.target.classList
    parentElem.classList.toggle('active')
    if (eventElmClassList.contains('toggler')) {
      eventElmClassList.toggle('active')
    } else if (eventElmClassList.contains('faq-title')) {
      const i = event.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
      i.classList.toggle('active')
    }
  }
}

faqContainer.addEventListener('click', showFaqContent)
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'poppins';
  background: #ECE9E6;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.main-container h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(54, 94, 128);
}

.main-container h1 i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-container h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(70, 131, 180, 0.507);
}

.main-container h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(70, 131, 180);
  animation: slide .8s linear 0s infinite alternate both running;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(300%);
  }
}

.faq-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
}

.faq {
  position: relative;
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  border-bottom: .5px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.829);
}

.faq-title {
  color: steelblue;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .1s linear;
}

.faq.active h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.faq-content {
  /* display: none; */
  font-family: 'nunito', 'sans-serif';
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(54, 94, 128);
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  color: hsl(208, 41%, 20%);
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.faq.active .faq-content {
  /* display: block; */
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: auto;
}

.faq .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.faq .toggler.active {
  color: hsl(208, 41%, 50%);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Day-12 Faq Boxes</title>
  <!-- google api/fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main-container">
    <h1><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> FAQ</h1>
    <div class="faq-box hide">
      <div class="faq">
        <h3 class="faq-title">How many team members can i invite?</h3>
        <p class="faq-content">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq">
        <h3 class="faq-title">What is the maximux file upload size?</h3>
        <p class="faq-content">No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq">
        <h3 class="faq-title">How do i reset my password?</h3>
        <p class="faq-content">Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq">
        <h3 class="faq-title">Can i cancel my subscription?</h3>
        <p class="faq-content">Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq">
        <h3 class="faq-title">Do you provide any additional support?</h3>
        <p class="faq-content">Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- fontawesome script -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39350fd9df.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Javascript -->
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a background animation instead:

```css
.main-container h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(54, 94, 128);
  padding-bottom:5px;
}

.main-container h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  animation: slide .8s linear infinite alternate;
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgb(70, 131, 180) 0 0) left/25% 3px no-repeat
    rgba(70, 131, 180, 0.507);
}


@keyframes slide {
  50% {
     background-size:50% 3px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>FAQ</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i had in mind.
Also is there a way to make the animation more smooth at both ends?

Comment: @PixieDust maybe try something different from linear: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Answer (score 1):

Here are two smoother animations. The difference between the two is one has starting/ending `width: 15%`, whereas the other has `width: 0`. You can also experiment with more divisions e.g. 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'poppins';
  background: #ECE9E6;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.main-container,
.main-container-2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.main-container h1,
.main-container-2 h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(54, 94, 128);
}

.main-container h1 i,
.main-container-2 h1 i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-container h1::before,
.main-container-2 h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(70, 131, 180, 0.507);
}

.main-container h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(70, 131, 180);
  animation: slide 2s linear 0s infinite alternate both running;
}

@keyframes slide {
  50% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 15%;
    left: 85%;
  }
}

.main-container-2 h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(70, 131, 180);
  animation: slide2 2s linear 0s infinite alternate both running;
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  50% {
    width: 40%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Day-12 Faq Boxes</title>
  <!-- google api/fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main-container">
    <h1><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> FAQ</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container-2">
    <h1><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> FAQ</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- fontawesome script -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39350fd9df.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Javascript -->
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```